# How to use AnimateStyle with Stylesheet.create

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-reanimated

I am using react-native-reanimated to create an Animated.View. I want to add a dynamic style to this Animated.View by changing the scale based on some state. This is my code:

```
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';

...
...
const scaleNode = useRef(new Animated.Value(1));

const style = useMemo(() => {
    return StyleSheet.create({
      animated: {transform: [{scale: scaleNode.current}]},
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Animated.View style={[style.animated, containerStyle]}>
...
...
```

I am using typescript, and while I have figured out that the style definition for the styles that i pass to `Animated.View` should be `Animated.AnimateStyle<ViewStyle>`. I am not sure about how to add types to the style that I am defining as a separate variable (which gets created with `Stylesheet.create`). In the current code, I get a ts error on transform:

```
Type 'AnimatedValue<1>' is not assignable to type 'number'
```

Note that if I directly pass the transform style to Animated.View, it does not complain

Comment: You need to use `useAnimatedStyle`: https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/api/hooks/useAnimatedStyle/

Comment: And you should probably move `StyleSheet` outside the component. It’s not intended to be used this way.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the `Animated` API from `react-native-reanimated` with the default from `react-native`.

`react-native-reanimated` does not have `Animated.Value`. Instead you should be using `useSharedValue`:

```js
const scale = useSharedValue(1); // 1 = initial value, also no useRef needed

const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
   return {
       transform: [{ scale: scale.value }],
   }
})

return <Animated.View style={[styles.yourStaticStyles, animatedStyle]} />
```